# Converting python Dataframe to Matlab file

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, dataframe, tuples

I am trying to convert a python Dataframe to a Matlab (.mat) file.

I initially have a txt (EEG signal) that I import using panda.read_csv:

`MyDataFrame = pd.read_csv("data.txt",sep=';',decimal='.')`, data.txt being a 2D array with labels. This creates a dataframe which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRnDp.png).

In order to convert it to .mat, I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669137/python-pandas-dataframe-to-matlab-struct-using-scipy-io/30707049) where the idea is to convert the dataframe into a dictionary of lists but after trying every aspect of this solution it's still unsuccessful.

`scipy.io.savemat('EEG_data.mat', {'struct':MyDataFrame.to_dict("list")})`

It did create a .mat file but it did not save my dataframe properly. The file I obtain after looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAoDg.png), so all the values are basically gone, and the remaining labels you see are empty when you look into them.

I also tried using [mat4py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mat4py/0.4.0) which is designed to export python structures into Matlab files, but it did not work either. I don't understand why, because converting my dataframe to a dictionary of lists is exactly what should be done according to the mat4py documentation.

Comment: This looks like a useful contribution but can you rewrite it into a question and then supply your answer as an answer? Also it might be helpful to see some example data.

Comment: Of course, I will do this tonight when I get back home.

Comment: Cool. When I needed to do this conversion the dictionary-of-lists approach worked for me, but clearly there is something different about your data and/or your environment. What versions of python, scipy and MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6, MATLAB R2017b and the version of scipy that is shipped with anaconda which I installed recently (last week).

It may come either from my data or from changes in recent versions, I honestly don't know.
[Here are what the first lines of my raw data look like.](https://imgur.com/qemBcI6)

Comment: If you could share that data extract in text form, I'd be happy to play around with it to see if I get the same problem and if so to try and figure out what's going on.

Comment: With pleasure, let me know if you find anything interesting ! Although I should warn you that it's a quite huge file (1,7GB). [Here you go](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7d2db09280ab59fb73f15939884fc3e720180223151447/4a44f2). This is the raw, untouched file.


Of course, when I was trying to find a solution I only used a small fraction of this dataset, like the 10 first lines, since it seemed to be a structural problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the reason the previous solutions haven't worked for you is that your `DataFrame` column names are not valid MATLAB `struct` field names, because they contain spaces and/or start with digit characters.

When I do:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.io
MyDataFrame = pd.read_csv('eeg.txt',sep=';',decimal='.')
truncDataFrame = MyDataFrame[0:1000] # reduce data size for test purposes
scipy.io.savemat('EEGdata1.mat', {'struct1':truncDataFrame.to_dict("list")})
```

the result in MATLAB is a struct with the 4 fields `reltime`, `datetime`, `iSensor` and `quality`. Each of these has 1000 elements, so the data from these columns has been converted, but the rest of your data is missing.

However if I first rename the DataFrame columns:

```
truncDataFrame.rename(columns=lambda x:'col_' + x.replace(' ', '_'), inplace=True)  
scipy.io.savemat('EEGdata2.mat', {'struct2':truncDataFrame.to_dict("list")})
```

the result in MATLAB is a struct with 36 fields. This is not the same format as your mat4py solution but it does contain (as far as I can see) all the data from the source DataFrame.

(Note that in your question, you are creating a `.mat` file that contains a variable called `struct` and when this is loaded into MATLAB it masks the builtin `struct` datatype - that might also cause issues with subsequent MATLAB code.)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I saw, these 4 fields and not the remaining data. The spaces and numbers should indeed explain this behaviour. 
I manually removed these characters (for the sake of it) and it worked normally.

It's a file given to me by my superior so I'll warn him about this formatting.

Thank you immensly for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212855/how-can-i-create-a-matlab-struct-array-from-scipy-io). There, the poster did not create a dictionary of lists but a dictionary of integers, which worked on my side. It is a small example, easily reproductible. Then I tried to manually add lists by entering values like [1, 2], an it did not work. But what worked was when I manually added **tuples** !

**MyDataFrame needs to be converted to a dictionary** and if a dictionary of **lists** doesn't work, try with **tuples**.

For beginners : lists are contained by [] and tuples by (). [Here is an image showing both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxglx.png).

This worked for me:

```
import mat4py as mp
EEGdata = MyDataFrame.apply(tuple).to_dict()
mp.savemat('EEGdata.mat',{'structs': EEGdata})
```

EEGdata.mat should now be readable by Matlab, as it is on my side.

Comment: I assume your `mp.savemat` is the same thing as `scipy.io.savemat`?

Comment: It's actually not. In my case, since the export did not work with scipy.io.savemat, I used mat4py (0.4.0) which is a python tool specifically designed for this kind of task. It only consists of two functions : savemat and loadmat.

Comment: This is a valid alternative solution to the accepted one because what you get in MATLAB this way may be a more convenient format for accessing the data by row - `mystruct(345)` contains all fields from the 345th row of the DataFrame, and so on.